# 10 year old 35mm film roll 500T

Tags: iso, 35mm, fujifilm, bulk-load

Hello I have 50m of Fuji Eterna 500T from 2010. What ISO should I rate the film/canister?
Should I rate it as an 200ASA or 400ASA?

Comment: How was the roll stored? You are aware that this is a ECN-2 cinema film and not a regular C-41 still negative film?

Comment: Yes yes I develop at home. I don't know how was stored I've keep it in the fridge after I bought it. I've took a sample now and developed the negative looks faded (200iso), compare with vision3 from 2018.

Comment: [How do I shoot expired film?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90483/75526)

Answer (score 1):

Testing is the only real way to know, especially if you don't know the storage history.